# How to find mutual fund in the Yahoo Finance app?

Tags: mutual-funds, yahoo-finance

Let's say I have invested in a mutual fund "Axis Blue Chip fund direct plan" and I want to track it in the Yahoo finance app. When I search for the fund, I'm not sure why it's not there. Am I searching wrong?

I can't upload the image because I don't have the points.

Comment: Is this investment in a brokerage account or perhaps a retirement account?  Retirement accounts can offer funds that aren't publicly traded; in such cases your only source of information is the plan manager.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, retirement plans often use "classes" of a fund that are not publicly traded, so they don't show up on finance sites.

You could use a different class of the same fund as a proxy (the provider's website should give you tickers for each class) but you'd want to look at the *returns* to make sure they are compatible. The price may be different so compare the *relative changes* in price.

That said, when I googled the exact name of the fund I got a hit from Yahoo Finance under ticker 0P0000XVTL.BO. That ticker may be "hidden" from the search function within Yahoo though, so you may not be able to add it to your "portfolio".

Answer (score 0):

Google: Axis Blue Chip

Go to their web site.

Select the fund name and the date range and you'll see the NAVs.

Comment: Hi Bob. I can see the nav, but I just want to track it in a single app with multiple mutual funds. I found out that the mutual funds have an AMFI code that can be searched in the Yahoo finance app. But that code is nowhere to be found.